# blackberry java gps

Tags: blackberry

how to invoke gps to find my location in blackberry via simulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a physical GPS receiver attached to the machine on which the simulator is running, you will not be able to obtain GPS coordinates. What you can do is to make a dummy class that acts as the GPS device itself. This should allow you more control on how, when and what data do you supply to your program.

Comment: It's a very basic class that will 'act' as the GPS device. You call it instead of the actual device. Then, just before you deploy your application on the phone, just replace the class you are calling with the one that actually calls the GPS.